# How to break on property change?

Tags: typescript, breakpoints

The same question exists for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618278/breakpoint-on-property-change) but I don't think the solutions listed there apply for typescript.

Firstly I've an object of type `express.Request` and I want to debug its `body` member:

```
function test(req : express.Request, res :express.Response, next:(err:any)=>void) {


  req.defineProperty(body, 'someProp', { //Property 'defineProperty' does not exist on type 'Request'.
    get: function () {
        return req._body;
    },

    set: function (value) {
        debugger; // sets breakpoint
        obj._someProp = value;
    }
});
```

Comment: Typescript compiles to javascript, so you debug it just the same way. Unless you use ts-node or something

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev But it won't let me compile the code/ I have a requirement to write only in typescript if possible.

Comment: how will it not let you compile? What error exactly you see

Comment: If the code doesn't compile, where are you planning to "break" the code?

Comment: @JJJ It won't let my apply `defineProperty` to my object but this is part of the debugging.

Comment: TS does let you calling `Object.defineProperty`

Comment: Here's my suggestion: as this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), you would more likely get actual answers to your real problem if you showed the original code that doesn't work and asked directly why it doesn't work, instead of asking about the debugging method you've chosen which also doesn't work.

Comment: @JJJ Well you asked for it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784174/how-to-diagnose-passport-authenticate/52806132#52806132

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is called `Object.defineProperty` and it takes the object on which to define the property as the first argument.  The proper usage would be something like this:

```
function test(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: (err: any) => void) {

    Object.defineProperty(req, 'body', {
        get: function () {
            return req._body;
        },

        set: function (value) {
            debugger; // sets breakpoint
            req._body = value;
        }
    });
}
```